# Need help installing QGIS 2.0 Need GDAL then SQLite3 3.7.16

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, sqlite, osx

OSX 10.7.5  I need help installing QGIS 2.0   It says I then need GDAL.  When I try to install GDAL it says SQLite3 3.7.16 or newer framework is required.  I can't find SQLite3 3.7.16.

Answer (score 2):

The KyngChaos page is full of all the software and updates that you should need for QGIS 2.0. I recently just downloaded the new QGIS and it is working well.

The SQLite3 3.7.16 is there about halfway down the page.

http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks[image]

Comment: The user would be best suited by installing the GDAL_Complete.framework and possibly the GSL.framework (known to be needed by georeferencer plugin). Those should be the only supporting frameworks needed for a base Kyngchaos.com QGIS 2.0.1 install. If there is an error beyond that, please contact Kyngchaos.com about it.